# Can't update (deploy) page to Firebase host

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I looked for a while for similiar quest, but those solutions didn't work for me.

*firebase deploy* command doesn't change version on the web's url.
Even though there  is an update seen in the console there in no change seen in web.

I don't know if it's important but I run those commands from cmd

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

The page is updated, but your browser shows you the old version of the page. To fix this do a hard cache reset. Open the website in Chrome and press `ctrl + shift + r`.